# If then statement in R based on number of rows

Tags: r, if-statement

I have an equation that I want to apply to a list of files. This equation makes a calculation based on water depth and density. I have data every 1 meter for all files. This equation works when the water is greater than 30m (sheet has more than 30 rows). How do I incorporate an if then statement to tell R to plug in "0" or "NA" if there are equal to or less than 30 rows in some files?

Here is my working code for files with more than 30 rows.

```
stratindex2=function(file){
    ctd2=read.csv(file)         
    ctd2=ctd2[-c(1:30),]
    x=ctd2$Density..sigma.t..kg.m.3..
    row=nrow(ctd2)              
    (x[row]-x[1])/(row-1)           
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a return and an if:

```
stratindex2=function(file){
    ctd2=read.csv(file)
    if(nrow(ctd2)<31){return(NA)}  
    ctd2=ctd2[-c(1:30),]
    x=ctd2$Density..sigma.t..kg.m.3..
    row=nrow(ctd2)              
    (x[row]-x[1])/(row-1)           
}
```